# How to add quotes to first row and first 2 columns (csv - command line)

Tags: csv, unix, sed, command-line

I am struggling a bit because I need to add double quotes to the first row and first two columns of a csv file as illustrated here:

**Input**

```
var1,var2,var3,var4   
x1,x2,x3,x4  
y1,y2,y3,y4
```

**Output:**

```
"var1","var2","var3","var4"  
"x1","x2",x3,x4  
"y1","y2",y3,y4
```

I have tried for a while now, and the closest thing I have come to is:

```
# add single quotes around columns of csv files
sed "s/[[:alnum:]]*/'&'/g" input.csv >output1.csv
# transform the single quotes into double quotes
tr "'" '"' < output1.csv > output2.csv
```

But this is putting quotes around all columns like this:

```
"var1","var2","var3","var4"  
"x1","x2","x3","x4"  
"y1","y2","y3","y4"
```

Are you, more experienced command line users, able to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can qualify substitution for particular line numbers

```
$ sed '1s/[^,]*/"&"/g; 2,$s/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/"\1","\2"/' ip.txt
"var1","var2","var3","var4"
"x1","x2",x3,x4
"y1","y2",y3,y4
```

- `1s/[^,]*/"&"/g` add quotes to all fields of first line
- `2,$s/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/"\1","\2"/` add quotes only for first two fields from 2nd line to end of file

Comment: I am curious to learn more about sed, but find the information rather confusing. How would this command be if the first row and the first 3 columns should be quoted? I tried putting an extra `, \([^,]*\)` (deletes the third column?)  in, as well as playing around with the numbers without luck. Thanks :-)

Comment: first 3 columns would be `2,$s/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/"\1","\2","\3"/` .... to learn more about sed, I have a comprehensive example based tutorial for GNU sed (https://github.com/learnbyexample/Command-line-text-processing/blob/master/gnu_sed.md) .. there a section dedicated for regular expressions.. you can also refer to resources mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info